# I am Building app with buildozer but building liblzma for armeabi-v7a having some exceptions

Tags: python, kivy, buildozer, kivymd

first I fired Buildozer init and After firing command 'buildozer -v android debug' . there is exception in building liblzma for armeabi-v7a .
This is my log below in short.

```
[INFO]:    <- directory context /home/manish/app/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
[INFO]:    -> running cp /home/manish/app/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/libffi/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21...(and 127 more)
[INFO]:    Building liblzma for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    -> directory context /home/manish/app/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/liblzma/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/liblzma
[INFO]:    -> running autoreconf -vif
           working: autoreconf: autopoint is needed because this package uses Gettext                                                                                  Exception in thread background thread for pid 19822:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/manish/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sh.py", line 1662, in wrap
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/manish/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sh.py", line 2606, in background_thread
    handle_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/home/manish/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sh.py", line 2304, in fn
    return self.command.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/home/manish/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sh.py", line 877, in handle_command_exit_code
    raise exc
sh.ErrorReturnCode_1:

  RAN: /usr/bin/autoreconf -vif

  STDOUT:
autoreconf: Entering directory `.'
autoreconf: running: autopoint --force
Can't exec "autopoint": No such file or directory at /usr/share/autoconf/Autom4te/FileUtils.pm line 345.
autoreconf: failed to run autopoint: No such file or directory
autoreconf: autopoint is needed because this package uses Gettext


  STDERR:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/manish/app/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 1260, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/manish/app/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/entrypoints.py", line 18, in main
    ToolchainCL()
  File "/home/manish/app/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 709, in __init__
    getattr(self, command)(args)
  File "/home/manish/app/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 154, in wrapper_func
    build_dist_from_args(ctx, dist, args)
  File "/home/manish/app/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 213, in build_dist_from_args
    build_recipes(build_order, python_modules, ctx,
  File "/home/manish/app/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/build.py", line 577, in build_recipes
    recipe.build_arch(arch)
  File "/home/manish/app/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/recipes/liblzma/__init__.py", line 24, in build_arch
    shprint(sh.Command('autoreconf'), '-vif', _env=env)
  File "/home/manish/app/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/logger.py", line 167, in shprint
    for line in output:
  File "/home/manish/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sh.py", line 925, in next
    self.wait()
  File "/home/manish/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sh.py", line 849, in wait
    self.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/home/manish/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sh.py", line 877, in handle_command_exit_code
    raise exc
sh.ErrorReturnCode_1:

  RAN: /usr/bin/autoreconf -vif

  STDOUT:
autoreconf: Entering directory `.'
autoreconf: running: autopoint --force
Can't exec "autopoint": No such file or directory at /usr/share/autoconf/Autom4te/FileUtils.pm line 345.
autoreconf: failed to run autopoint: No such file or directory
autoreconf: autopoint is needed because this package uses Gettext


  STDERR:

# Command failed: /usr/bin/python3 -m pythonforandroid.toolchain create --dist_name=myapp --bootstrap=sdl2 --requirements=python3,kivy,kivymd,os,math,pandas,xlsxwriter,time,threading,datetime,PIL,numpy --arch armeabi-v7a --copy-libs --color=always --storage-dir="/home/manish/app/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a" --ndk-api=21
# ENVIRONMENT:
#     SHELL = '/bin/bash'
#     WSL_DISTRO_NAME = 'Ubuntu'
#     NAME = 'LAPTOP-BR4UQ5CH'
#     PWD = '/home/manish/app'
#     LOGNAME = 'manish'
#     MOTD_SHOWN = 'update-motd'
#     HOME = '/home/manish'
#     LANG = 'C.UTF-8'
#     LS_COLORS = 'rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:'
#     LESSCLOSE = '/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s'
#     TERM = 'xterm-256color'
#     LESSOPEN = '| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s'
#     USER = 'manish'
#     SHLVL = '1'
#     WSLENV = ''
#     XDG_DATA_DIRS = '/usr/local/share:/usr/share:/var/lib/snapd/desktop'
#     PATH = ('/home/manish/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin:/home/manish/.local/bin:/home/manish/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/mnt/c/Program '
 'Files/WindowsApps/CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_2004.2020.812.0_x64__79rhkp1fndgsc:/mnt/c/Program '
 'Files/Common Files/Oracle/Java/javapath:/mnt/c/Program Files '
 '(x86)/Intel/iCLS Client/:/mnt/c/Program Files/Intel/iCLS '
 'Client/:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/system32:/mnt/c/WINDOWS:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/:/mnt/c/Program '
 'Files (x86)/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/DAL:/mnt/c/Program '
 'Files/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/DAL:/mnt/c/Program Files '
 '(x86)/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/IPT:/mnt/c/Program '
 'Files/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine '
 'Components/IPT:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/System32/OpenSSH/:/mnt/c/Program '
 'Files/Git/cmd:/mnt/c/Program Files/PuTTY/:/mnt/c/Program Files/Microsoft SQL '
 'Server/110/Tools/Binn/:/mnt/c/Program '
 'Files/Java/jdk-15/bin:/mnt/c/Users/Manish/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/Scripts:/mnt/c/Users/Manish/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37:/mnt/c/Users/Manish/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/Application:/mnt/c/Program '
 'Files/Mozilla '
 'Firefox:/mnt/c/Users/Manish/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/Scripts/:/mnt/c/Users/Manish/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/:/snap/bin')
#     HOSTTYPE = 'x86_64'
#     OLDPWD = '/home/manish'
#     _ = '/home/manish/.local/bin/buildozer'
#     PACKAGES_PATH = '/home/manish/.buildozer/android/packages'
#     ANDROIDSDK = '/home/manish/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk'
#     ANDROIDNDK = '/home/manish/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19c'
#     ANDROIDAPI = '27'
#     ANDROIDMINAPI = '21'
#
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

I don't understand how to solve this error .

```
[app]


title = Jpkundali

package.name = myapp

package.domain = org.test

source.dir = .

source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas

version = 0.1

requirements = python3,kivy,kivymd,os,math,pandas,xlsxwriter,time,threading,datetime,PIL,numpy

orientation = portrait



osx.python_version = 3

osx.kivy_version = 1.9.1

fullscreen = 0

android.arch = armeabi-v7a

ios.kivy_ios_url = https://github.com/kivy/kivy-ios
ios.kivy_ios_branch = master

ios.ios_deploy_url = https://github.com/phonegap/ios-deploy
ios.ios_deploy_branch = 1.7.0


[buildozer]

log_level = 2
warn_on_root = 1
```

This is my buildozer.spec file where i included all mu requirement libraries like python3,kivy,kivymd,os,math,pandas,xlsxwriter,time,threading,datetime,PIL,numpy . Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I observed that this problem occurs when I try to include pandas ! in buildozer.spec file

Answer (score 3):

Finally, I solved this problem for me. I used buildozer in docker environment, and hence, building pandas failed since some dependencies were missing.

So, I added some libraries to the actual docker file and build it again. Now, everything is working fine.

To sum up, I modified the following system relevant libraries:

```
# system requirements to build most of the recipes
RUN apt update -qq > /dev/null && \
    apt install -qq --yes --no-install-recommends \
    autoconf \
    automake \
    autopoint \  # added
    build-essential \
    ccache \
    cmake \
    gettext \
    git \
    libffi-dev \
    libltdl-dev \
    libssl-dev \
    liblzma-dev \  # added 
    libtool \
    openjdk-8-jdk \
    patch \
    pkg-config \
    python3-pip \
    python3-setuptools \
    sudo \
    unzip \
    zip \
    zlib1g-dev
```

Comment: Explain in detail, what exactly you did

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue with pandas being in the buildozer.spec file.

Based on Pandy's answer I tried:

```
sudo apt install -y autoconf automake autopoint build-essential ccache cmake gettext git libffi-dev libltdl-dev libssl-dev liblzma-dev libtool openjdk-8-jdk patch pkg-config python3-pip python3-setuptools sudo unzip zip zlib1g-dev
```

It worked for me. But I'm very new to buildozer, linux, and programming in general. So try it on your own risk